# Parser Alternative Operator | Fails

Tags: scala, parsing

Using an extension of the Scala parser, I wish to parse two different types of information – patterns and filters. These patterns and filters may appear in any order.

With the format for patterns and filters defined in the variables `pattern` and `filter`, respectively, I want to unite them so that filters and patterns may be supplied in any order:

```
val patternRepetition: Parser[List[ParsedPattern]] = {
  rep1sep(pattern, ".") <~ opt(".")
}

val patternOrFilter: Parser[List[ParsedPattern]] = {
  patternRepetition | rep1(filterSpec)
}

val patternList: Parser[List[ParsedPattern]] = {
  rep1(patternOrFilter) ^^ {
    _.flatten
  }
}
```

For reference, the code for `pattern` and `filter` are shown at the end of this post.

---

Some examples of what `patternList` is supposed to match:

```
?A ?C ?B .
```

```
?A ?C ?B .
FILTER(?A > ?B)
```

```
?A ?C ?B .
?A ?C ?B
FILTER(?A > ?B)
```

```
?A ?C ?B
FILTER(?A > ?B)
?A ?C ?B
```

---

As soon as a filter appears, the parser complains about an unexpected `(` character. However, changing `|` to `~` in `patternOrFilter` will successfully parse a list of patterns followed by a filter (such as in the second and third example), so I believe there is an issue with my use of the alternative operator `|`.

Therefore, my question is: **why does the `|` operator fail to recognize filters?**

---

A **pattern** is currently defined as the following:

```
val pattern: Parser[ParsedPattern] = {
  "?A" ~! "?C" ~! "?B" ^^ {
    case s ~ p ~ o =>
      ParsedPattern(s, p, o)
  }
}
```

This obviously matches:

```
?A ?C ?B
```

A **filter** is defined with the following code:

```
val filter: Parser[ParsedPattern] = {
  "FILTER(" ~> "?A" ~ ">" ~ "?B") <~ ")"  ^^ {
    case lhs ~ comp ~ rhs =>
      ParsedPattern(lhs, comp, rhs) 
  }
}
```

This matches the following line:

```
FILTER(?A > ?B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` parses ONE side only (patterns OR filter but not both).

Try a new rule like (change types, I used `_`):

```
def patternOrFilterAll: Parser[_] = {
  rep1(patternOrFilter)
}
```

You may need to change `patternRepetition` and `patternOrFilter` to get the return value you want.

**edit**

Your Parser does not work because of the usage of `~!`. If you use `~` instead the parser then your example will work (e.g. http://scalafiddle.net/console/97ea3cfb64eeaa1edba65501d0bb3c86 ).

The reason: The parser uses backtracking and `~!` will disable that. The parser needs backtracking because the `url` regex may fail.

Comment: Oh, right, I have added that to the problem description now. I already have that in my code, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a small *non-working* example? 

Here is a *working* example based on your question (I had to remove some code because I do not have ParsedPattern): http://scalafiddle.net/console/c359889a833e7612e0cff1dc69d272bc

Comment: Thanks for your time. This is the shortest I can get it to: http://scalafiddle.net/console/65d90fc6d307590b14e9e1800d4e8eab I apologize for the length. It seems that the URL part is causing trouble. With comments, I've pointed out three places where omitting something gets rid of the problem.